# JavaScript: How do I pass a variables in to a JS function, from a for loop?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, for-loop

```
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 {
   var Topic = x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var Content = x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.write("<li class='withimage'> ");
  document.write(Topic);
  document.write("<button onclick='show(Topic)'></button>");
  document.write("</span><span class='time'>");
  var full_time = x[i].getElementsByTagName("created_at")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var time = full_time.split("+");
  document.write(time[0]);
  document.write("</span></li>");

  }
```

My function is

```
function show(head)
{
document.getElementById("content").style.display="none";

document.getElementById("details").style.display="block";

document.getElementById("Heading").innerHTML=head;
}
```

But in every button click I got the final iterating value in the variable "Topic"

Comment: Because the value `Topic` is "hard-coded" in this this line: ` document.write("<button onclick='show(Topic)'></button>");`

Comment: closures in javascript. read it

Comment: To really fix your problem, you have to use at least traditional event handlers, not inline event handlers, so that you make use of closures (in combination with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)) and not use global variables, like in your case. More info: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not passing the `Topic` Object for each button. Actually you are passing just the object name. So when you click on any button it 'll search for the variable `Topic` which in this case 'll be the last `Topic` object in your iteration.

you try something like this :

```
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 {
   var Topic = x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var Content = x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.write("<li class='withimage'> ");
  document.write(Topic);
  document.write("<button onclick='show(" + Topic + ")'></button>");
  document.write("</span><span class='time'>");
  var full_time = x[i].getElementsByTagName("created_at")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var time = full_time.split("+");
  document.write(time[0]);
  document.write("</span></li>");

  }
```